# PHP Echo from multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to echo the "name" variable from this array.

```
array(2) {
    ["error"] => bool(false)["response"] => array(8) {
        ["id"] => int(560277)["name"] => string(7)
        "Jeff" ["avatar"] => string(55)
        "https://etc.etc" ["joinDate"] => string(19)
        "2015-09-21 16:47:53" ["steamID64"] => int(76521228272726998)
    ["groupName"] => string(6)
        "Player" ["groupID"] => int(1)["permissions"] => array(2) {
            ["isGameAdmin"] => bool(false)["showDetailedOnWebMaps"] => bool(false)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to access it, I've tried:
`json->response->name;`, but this won't work because this is an array not an object and `json[0]["response"]["name"];`

EDIT:
The array is coming from a json API, here is an example. https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/2

I am then converting that using

```
$json = (json_decode($tmpServer, true, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

Comment: try json['response']['name']

Comment: @girish I tried `echo($json['response']['name']);`, but the output is empty.

Comment: can you show how you have formed the array and whether it is converted from javascript to php?

Comment: @girish I have edited the original post with some more information

Comment: what happens to `json[0]["response"]["name"];`?

Comment: I have added it as the answer you can mark it if worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it working on php fiddle like this

```
$arr = file_get_contents("https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/2");

$decoded = json_decode($arr,true);

echo $decoded["response"]["name"];
```